# Slicing a string to read a html document in VB

Tags: html, vb.net

I was hoping someone could help me figure out why this script will not return the link names. I am trying to return a sub-string from 'http://textfiles.com/directory.html' which just writes the link names to the console, but I am struggling. The main problem - as far as I can see - is in the 'do until' loop. The working code outputs the html text to the console more for my sake than anything else (it does this successfully), but this feature may also help you guys understand the total picture I am facing. Maybe after seeing the code/ understanding my goal you guys can see where I am going wrong AND/OR suggest a better method for achieving my goal. Thanks a ton!

Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text

Module Module1

```
Sub Main()

    Dim line As String = ""
    Dim lowBound As String = "<a href="""
    Dim highBound As String = """>"
    Console.WriteLine("Grab link names from textfiles.com")
    Console.WriteLine("")
    Dim siteName As String = "http://textfiles.com/directory.html"

    Dim tmpString As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder
    My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(siteName, "C:\~\VisualStudio\BeginnerPractice\TextFileDotCom_GrabLinkNames\TextFileDotCom_GrabLinkNames\bin\debug\directory.html", False, 500)
    Dim myReader As StreamReader = New StreamReader("C:\~\VisualStudio\BeginnerPractice\TextFileDotCom_GrabLinkNames\TextFileDotCom_GrabLinkNames\bin\debug\directory.html")
    While Not IsNothing(line)
        line = myReader.ReadLine()
        If Not IsNothing(line) Then
            tmpString.Append(line)
        End If
    End While

    Dim pageText As String = tmpString.ToString
    Console.WriteLine(pageText)
    Dim intCounter As Integer = 1

    Do Until intCounter >= Len(pageText)
        Dim checkSub As String = Mid(pageText, intCounter + 1, (Len(pageText) - intCounter))
        Dim positLow As Integer = InStr(checkSub, lowBound)
        Dim positHigh As Integer = InStr(checkSub, highBound)
        If (positLow > 0 And positHigh > 0) And positLow < positHigh Then
            Dim indexLow As Integer = checkSub.IndexOf(lowBound)
            Dim indexHigh As Integer = checkSub.IndexOf(highBound)
            Dim foundLink As String = checkSub.Substring(indexLow + Len(lowBound), indexHigh - Len(highBound))
            Console.WriteLine(foundLink)
            intCounter = intCounter + (Len(lowBound) + Len(highBound) + Len(foundLink) - 1)
        Else
            intCounter = Len(pageText)
        End If
    Loop

    Console.ReadLine()
    myReader.Close()
    My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile("C:\~\VisualStudio\BeginnerPractice\TextFileDotCom_GrabLinkNames\TextFileDotCom_GrabLinkNames\bin\debug\directory.html")
End Sub
```

End Module

Comment: ..I was hasty in this post - didn't comment the code out. LMK if you guys need a re-post with comments

Comment: You can do it much easier using either the Webbrowser control or the MSHTML object library. Instead of trying to parse the text yourself, you can load it into an HTML Document and get all the anchor elements and just loop over them. The webbrowser control is the easiest since you can just navigate to the url and once the document is loaded, access the dom

Comment: Thanks, I am going to look into these today - I appreciate the help.